# break-pointing c++ files in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have just downloaded the `Android Studio` version mainly because I want ti use the break-point debugger of `c/c++` `JNI` files.

The app runs well and the code seems to be correctly compiled and ran but when I set a break point, I get this message

`there is no executable code at my_file.cpp:some_line_number`

Comment: You can't debug C/C++ files with Android Studio.  It is a Java IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the **NDK Preview** (available from Android Studio 1.3 RC1) you need to use the *Gradle experimental plugin for Android*.

**First of all, follow the instructions [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview)**.

---

Pay attention to the ***Debugging*** section, which explains how to debug:

> To debug the project, you'll need to create a native run
> configuration. Invoke Run > Edit Configurations..., then choose the
> Native configuration type:

[image]

> Name the configuration, and choose the module to run. If you run into
> bugs with the LLDB debugger in this version of the IDE, you can try
> switching to the GDB debugger instead as a workaround.

[image]

---